# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null because of my siblingElement method

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
/* Nonfications, Thanks to MDN */
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Take a break!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
notifyMe()

//Read localStorage:
/*
if (localStorage.getItem('object') === undefined) {
  localStorage.setItem('object', '')
} else {
  //let objectData = localStorage.getItem('object');
  let objectData = {
    section: {
      heading: {
        task: 'label'
      }
    },
    studyRoutine: {
      onweekdays: {
        mathBook: 'important'
      },
      onweekends: {
        mathBook: 'important',
        scienceBook: 'notimportant'
      }
    }
  }
  alert(objectData[1])
  // loop sections
  alert(objectData.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < objectData.length; i++) {
    // loop headings
    for (var y = 0; y < objectData[i].length; y++) {
      // loop tasks
      for (var x = 0; x < objectData[i][y].length; x++) {
        const myElementMade = document.createElement('input');
        myElementMade.setAttribute('type', 'text')

      }
    }
  }
}
*/
/* Add deleted elements and refer to it when created in same place / position */
window.deletedSections = [];
window.deletedHeadings = [];
window.deletedTasks = [];
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebarTasks');
/* Counts each element so they can have different id's to be selected */
window.counter = 0;
window.counterHeadings = 0;
window.counterLabel = 0;
window.counterLabelDelete = 0;
window.counterTasks = 0;
window.counterBr = 0;
/* To avoid any interferance there is a seperate delete function for tasks(because properties of tasks differ) */
const deleteTask = (taskid) => {

}
/* Delete sections and headings */
const deleteType = (labelAdd, labelDelete, inputType, spacing) => {
  /* Remove elements given as id's */
  document.getElementById(labelAdd).remove()
  /* Insert div so div can be used to append later */
  //document.getElementById(labelDelete).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div id="${inputType}"></div>`)
  document.getElementById(labelDelete).remove()
  document.getElementById(inputType).remove()
  document.getElementById(spacing).remove()
  /* Check if inputType is section or heading */

  //if (inputType.slice(0, 7) === 'element') {
    /* Push to section counter */
    //window.deletedSections.push(inputType)
  //} else if (inputType.slice(0, 7) === 'heading') {
    /* Push to heading counter */
    //window.deletedHeadings.push(inputType)
  //}
}
/* New task */
const newTask = (id, labelid) => {
  // Counter tasks for id's that work
  window.counterTasks++
  window.counterLabel++
  const heading = document.getElementById(id);
  const label = document.getElementById(labelid);
  // Insert task input
  label.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br><input placeholder="task" name="task" type="text" id="task${window.counterTasks}" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;"></input>`)
  // Insert button to go to the task
  document.getElementById(`task${window.counterTasks}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<label for="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;" id="label${window.counterLabel}"><button onclick="checkTask()">></button></label>`)
}
const newHeading = (id, labelid) => {
  const sectionElement = document.getElementById(id);
  // Counter for headings and id's
  window.counterHeadings++
  window.counterLabel++
  // test declared to fix some bugs but might be unnessary
  const test = 'element' + window.counterHeadings;
  // creat heading input
  //document.getElementById(`${labelid}`)
  /*
  if (window.counterHeadings > 1) {
    if (document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings - 1}`).nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id.slice(0, 4) !== 'task') {
      document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings - 1}`).nextElementSibling.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br><input placeholder="heading" name="heading" type="text" id="heading${window.counterHeadings}" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"></input>`)
      // insert label button "+"
      document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;" id="label${window.counterLabel}"><button onclick="newTask('heading${window.counterHeadings}', 'label${window.counterLabel}')">+</button></label>`);
    } else {
      alert(document.querySelectorAll(`#heading${window.counterHeadings - 1} > *`));
      document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings - 1}`).nextElementSibling.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br><input placeholder="heading" name="heading" type="text" id="heading${window.counterHeadings}" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"></input>`)
      // insert label button "+"
      document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;" id="label${window.counterLabel}"><button onclick="newTask('heading${window.counterHeadings}', 'label${window.counterLabel}')">+</button></label>`);
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(`${labelid}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br><input placeholder="heading" name="heading" type="text" id="heading${window.counterHeadings}" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"></input>`)
  // insert label button "+"
  document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;" id="label${window.counterLabel}"><button onclick="newTask('heading${window.counterHeadings}', 'label${window.counterLabel}')">+</button></label>`);
  }
  */
  if (window.counterHeadings > 1) {
    window.counter = 0;
    window.counterPrev = [labelid];
    while (true) {
      console.log(window.counterPrev[counter]);
      window.counterPrev.push(document.getElementById(window.counterPrev[window.counterPrev.length]).nextElementSibling.id)
      window.counter++
      if (window.counter > 20) {
        break;
      }
  }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(`${labelid}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br><input placeholder="heading" name="heading" type="text" id="heading${window.counterHeadings}" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"></input>`)
    // insert label button "+"
    document.getElementById(`heading${window.counterHeadings}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;" id="label${window.counterLabel}"><button onclick="newTask('heading${window.counterHeadings}', 'label${window.counterLabel}')">+</button></label>`);
  }
}
const addSection = () => {
  // counter for section, label and <br>
  window.counter++
  window.counterLabel++
  window.counterBr++
  const newSection = document.createElement('input');
  // add attributes to section and appendChild() because section is not moved to the right so this is a better aprroach
  newSection.setAttribute('placeholder', 'section');
  newSection.setAttribute('name', 'section');
  newSection.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  newSection.id = 'element' + window.counter;
  // test again
  const test = 'element' + window.counter;
  sidebar.appendChild(newSection)
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  // label with "+"
  label.setAttribute('for', 'section');
  label.innerHTML = `<button onclick="newHeading('element${window.counter}', 'label${window.counterLabel}')">+</button>`;
  label.id = `label${window.counterLabel}`;
  console.log(label.innerHTML);
  sidebar.appendChild(label)
  // delete label "X"
  document.getElementById(`label${window.counterLabel}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<label for="section" id="labelDelete${window.counterLabelDelete}"><button onclick="deleteType('label${window.counterLabel}', 'labelDelete${window.counterLabelDelete}', 'element${window.counter}', 'br${window.counterBr}')">X</button></label>`)
  // br has id so can be deleted and not take up space.
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  br.id = `br${window.counterBr}`;
  sidebar.appendChild(br);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sidebarTasks">
      <button onclick="addSection()">Add new section</button> <br>
    <input id="" name="section" type="text" placeholder="section"> <label for="section"><button id="">+</button></label> <br>
    <input id="" name="heading" type="text" placeholder="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"> <label for="heading" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"><button id="" onclick="newTask(this.id)">+</button></label> <br>
    <input id="" name="task" type="text" placeholder="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;" style="position: relative; left: 2vw;"> <label for="task" style="position: relative; left: 4vw;"><button id="">></button></label> <br>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(please don't take any code from here I worked hard)

Try making a new section, pressing the + twice and you see the error.

There is a lot of code but focus on:

```
if (window.counterHeadings > 1) {
    window.counter = 0;
    window.counterPrev = [labelid];
    while (true) {
      console.log(window.counterPrev[counter]);
      window.counterPrev.push(document.getElementById(window.counterPrev[window.counterPrev.length]).nextElementSibling.id)
      window.counter++
      if (window.counter > 20) {
        break;
      }
  }
```

I'm trying to make it so I can iterate through each element after my heading input but it keeps on giving errors that say it's null or `.nextElementSibling` is getting a wrong property, what I'm getting is Javascript can't find the element id I'm giving it but I don't know why, it should be correct based on my knowledge.

EDIT:
This was my code before

```
 if (window.counterHeadings > 1) {
    window.counter = 0;
    window.counterPrev = `${labelid}`
    while (true) {
      console.log(window.counterPrev);
      window.counterPrev = document.getElementById(window.counterPrev).nextElementSibling.id
      window.counter++
      if (window.counter > 20) {
        break;
      }
  }
```

Please note I'm new at Javascript and I'm only at regex section in freecodecamp so please explain everything you say, thank you!

Comment: `window.counterPrev[window.counterPrev.length])` is `undefined`, because arrays have zero-based indexing.

Comment: @Teemu But my counter variable starts at zero? So it will go [0], [1] so on

Comment: You've set `window.counterPrev = [labelid];` just above the the loop, so `window.counterPrev.length` is `1`, but the last (and only) index of `window.counterPrev` is `0`. Notice, that arguments are evaluated before `push` is executed.

Comment: @Teemu  the edit i made was the code i had before but that doesn't work

Comment: Just return the code to what you first had on the question, and do `window.counterPrev[window.counterPrev.length - 1]`.

Comment: @Teemu still null

Comment: Then there's no element with the given id.

Comment: Yes but ``` console.log(window.counterPrev[window.counterPrev]); ``` which is without the -1 gives me what I want but also gives a error, it gives label1 which is the id I do want but I want it to go even further